# mysql num_row check for multiple post values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to perform num_row check for multiple input fields, to check if all fields have emails which are in the database. and if one field is not in the database it should echo that that value is not a registered email.also if the field is empty it ignores it unless all fields are empty in which case it echos a message. what I have made is flawed, as it doesn't works if the first input field is empty. is there a better way to to this?

```
foreach($_POST as $value){
        $usercheck =  "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$value'";
        $usercheck = $db->query($usercheck);

        if($usercheck->num_rows !== 0 || $value =="") 
          {
            $valid="1";
          }
               break;
       }

     if(empty($value))
 {
    echo "none filled in";
 }  else
    if ($valid == "1")
{
   echo "all good";
}  else
{
  echo $value." is not a user";
}
```

Comment: If you only have 1 email per user, you should limit your MySQL query to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely.

```
// Dump all of $_POST into a long, concatenated string
// results in: field1','field2','field3
$group = implode( "','", $_POST );

$sql_statement = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email IN ('$group'); ";
$results = $db->query( $sql_statement );

if ( $results->num_rows > 0 ){
    // valid
} else {
    // not valid
}
```

Comment: I knew there had to be better. Thank you for showing me, this looks perfect. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
$list = implode('`,`', $_POST);
$usercheck =  "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email IN ('$value')";
$usercheck = $db->query($usercheck);

if(empty($_POST)) {
    echo "all good";
} elseif($usercheck->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "none filled in";
} else {
    echo "$value is not a user";
}
```

Notice that your code is unsafe and could be exploited with SQL injections.
To prevent this you can:

- use [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
- use [MySqli's prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (*suggested*)
- use PDO (*suggested*)

Comment: This looks very similar to my earlier post. But, you have a couple of errors that need correcting. Replace `$value` with `$list` in line 2... include apostrophes in your `glue` for `implode()` on line 1, otherwise you get $list = 'field1,field2,field3' which, unless they are integers, will break the query. MySQL expects IN( 1, 2, 3) or for strings, IN( 'one', 'two', 'three' ). Not IN('one, two, three').

Answer (score 0):

inside the foreach loop,

u seem to be breaking in the first iteration itself.
how would it go to the next one i wonder. i removed the break and moved the other code inside your foreach loop which was outside it.

```
  foreach($_POST as $value){
            $usercheck =  "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$value'";
            $usercheck = $db->query($usercheck);

            if($usercheck->num_rows !== 0 || $value =="") 
              {
                $valid="1";
              }
        if(empty($value))
     {
        echo "none filled in";
     }  else
        if ($valid == "1")
    {
       echo "all good";
    }  else
    {
      echo $value." is not a user";
    }



       }
```